# O que é Crow's Foot em relação a Banco de Dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Na aula de banco de dados o professor mencionou um termo chamado **Crow's Foot**, e este termo me deixou confuso.

Eu gostaria de saber o que é Crow's Foot em relação a Banco de Dados?

Answer (score 2):

> **Notação Crow's Foot (Pé de Galinha)**: Esta é a notação mais amplamente utilizada dentre os arquitetos de dados. Sua implementação
>   é feita através de retângulos representando as entidades, linhas
>   representando os relacionamentos e traços representando a
>   cardinalidade, onde a cardinalidade “muitos” é representada por um
>   “tridente” aparentando um “pé de galinha”, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tem muito o que adicionar da [descrição do devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/projeto-de-banco-de-dados-parte-1/10923).

---

**OBS**: Jefferson Quesado levantou a questão de o termo usado pelo devmedia ser diferente do termo perguntado aqui; ele está errado no site (link que adicionei) mas a explicação está ok.

Comment: Então o AP cometeu um typoh?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, não entendi o "typoh"

Comment: Fui ver aqui, o correto é typo, vem de **erro tipográfico** em inglês https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error?wprov=sfti1; então, "typo" = "erro de escrita"

Comment: não tinha percebido, mas acho que o erro não foi do AP e sim do devmedia o.O

Comment: segundo a wiki, foi erro do devmedia mesmo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_diagram?wprov=sfti1